# Last line on Emacs

Tags: emacs

[image]

As you can see in that image, I can move my cursor to the last line (if I use RET on the last column of the last line), and the last line doesn't appear on the left line number column.

It is also not highlighted, but as soon as I type on it, like if I enter an "a", it will be highlighted and appear on the line number list on the left.

This is a very tiny bug, but it slightly annoys me - it really isn't a major issue, but I'd really like a way to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc7

Comment: malenkiy_scot, good point, it seems like I've only been rating them up, instead of really choosing one, I will do it in all my questions now! thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you use the `Linum` package for your line numbers (in the left-hand margin), [here's](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc7) the patch that numbers the last line of the buffer:

```lisp
--- linum.el-rev474.svn000.tmp.el   Fri May 08 11:30:24 2009
+++ linum.el    Fri May 08 11:29:38 2009
@@ -135,8 +135,15 @@
-  (let ((line (line-number-at-pos))
-        (limit (window-end win t))
-        (fmt (cond ((stringp linum-format) linum-format)
-                   ((eq linum-format 'dynamic)
-                    (let ((w (length (number-to-string
-                                      (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
-                      (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "d")))))
-        (width 0))
+  (let* ((line (line-number-at-pos))
+         (limit (window-end win t))
+         ;; set empty-line-at-eob flag
+         (empty-line-at-eob (or (equal ?\n (char-before (point-max)))
+                                (equal (point-min) (point-max))))
+         ;; we will automatically number the line at eob if it's not empty
+         ;; (so we'll say it's already done)
+         (numbered-line-at-eob (not empty-line-at-eob))
+         (fmt (cond ((stringp linum-format) linum-format)
+                    ((eq linum-format 'dynamic)
+                     (let* ((c (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))
+                            (w (length (number-to-string
+                                        (+ c (if empty-line-at-eob 1 0))))))
+                       (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "d")))))
+         (width 0))
@@ -146 +153,2 @@
-    (while (and (not (eobp)) (<= (point) limit))
+    ;; stop if point>limit, or if eobp and numbered-line-at-eob
+    (while (and (not (and (eobp) numbered-line-at-eob)) (<= (point) limit))
@@ -165,0 +174,4 @@
+      ;; before moving forward, if we're already at eob
+      (if (eobp)
+          ;; then we've numbered the empty line
+          (setq numbered-line-at-eob t))
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to apply this patch?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's not a bug.  The line is empty and there is nothing on it.  So it doesn't really count as "a line" until content is on it.  The very last character in the file is the newline character on line 99.  Line 100 is functionally treated as "it doesn't exist" until there is content on it.

Comment: Agreed: if the OP will simply run `wc` against the file that is shown in the screenshot, they will quickly become convinced that the file actually does have only 99 lines until they begin typing characters past the 99th line's newline to create a 100th.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit [linum.el](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/linum/linum.html) if you really want to change the functionality. [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc7) is the code to do what you want.

You should be aware it isn't a bug, though. What you want is subjective; it was a design decision.